# Access Multiple Model Property within the script tag in cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to access a Multiple Models property within  (ASP.NET MVC 5 .cshtml page) ?

I have created a general model combined with more then 3 model,i need to use one of them within script tag for my view page. I have tried number of solutions.nothing work.i need to do like  this for condition checking and get the value from the Model.

i.e

```
 $(document).read(function(){
  var Model.modelname_1.SomeProperty;
 })
```

Comment: Yes Definitely this is possible Like

Answer (score 1):

yes Its possible you can access with following syntax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var pro1 = '@Model.Model1.Name';
var pro2 = '@Model.Model2.CellNumber';
});
```